# How to quit CefClient totally On MacOS

Tags: chromium-embedded

```
- (void)terminate:(id)sender {
    ClientAppDelegate* delegate = static_cast<ClientAppDelegate*>(
   [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate] );
   [delegate tryToTerminateApplication:self];
   // Return, don't exit. The application is responsible for exiting on its own.
} 


- (void)tryToTerminateApplication:(NSApplication*)app {
   NSLog(@"tryToTerminateApplication ");
    client::MainContext::Get()->GetRootWindowManager()->CloseAllWindows(false);
 }
```

I tried `“client::MainContext::Get()->GetRootWindowManager()->CloseAllWindows(false); ”，`the default root window is been closed，but the CefClient app still in the Dock，then click the app icon，it can not open window again,

My question is why CloseAllWindows cant Terminate the CefClient totally,
How could i  achieve this effect？Im An Android dever,know little about CEF on Mac,

Thank you very much anyway,

Comment: CEF has two example applications: cefsimple and cefclient. Take a look at these.

Comment: I have saw  cefsimple, but the code about quit application are both same, but cefclient cant quit totally by CloseAllWindows(false), I dont know why,

Comment: Are you saying that both cefsimple and cefclient applications (original unmodified examples) do not quit application?

Comment: @CzarekTomczak   I mean cefsimple is OK，But cefclient cant quit Application，I m new of C++ and Mac dev，Can u resolve my problems plz ：）

Comment: You should report issue in the CEF tracker.